# Trying to draw a string onto a camera in XNA, but it remains stationary when the Camera moves

Tags: xna, camera, position

I'm trying to draw a string into my game (Using XNA) (The string is an FPS counter). I was attempting to get it to follow the camera. However, when I draw the string, it remains in the same place when the camera moves. Do I have to use matrix's and transforms?

Thanks,

Lewis

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is moving and you don't want the string to move, just use a second spritebatch to draw the gui elements that are not relative to camera and don't move on the screen.

Moving GUI elements to keep up with the camera seems unnecessary.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(cameraTransform)
//camera related game elements
spriteBatch.End()

spriteBatch.Begin()
//draw GUI elements
spriteBatch.End()
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't think to use another Spritebatch, that's great, thanks :)